# Unable to access link except by clicking button on website

Tags: python, html, python-requests

So there is a link from a website I have been trying to access using python requests library. Normally on clicking the button, it redirects to another website but copying and pasting the referrer link either in the browser directly or using requests.get() only returns the referrer page.
The link to the referrer page is: "https://www.thenetnaija.net/videos/kdrama/16426-alchemy-of-souls/season-1/episode-7"

Here's the html with the button

```
<a
              href="https://www.thenetnaija.net/videos/kdrama/16426-alchemy-of-souls/season-1/episode-7/download"
              class="btn"
              type="submit"
              title="Download Video"
            >
                <i class="fas fa-download"></i> Download <i class="fas fa-file-video"></i>
                <span class="small-text">(Video)</span>
</a>
```

if I try to copy and paste the link ("https://www.thenetnaija.net/videos/kdrama/16426-alchemy-of-souls/season-1/episode-7/download") directly in browser, it redirects to this link ("https://www.thenetnaija.net/videos/kdrama/16426-alchemy-of-souls/season-1/episode-7") instead of this ("https://www.sabishare.com/file/mHxiMiZHW15-alchemy-of-souls-s01e07-netnaija-com-mp4")

so the only way to get to this url ("https://www.sabishare.com/file/mHxiMiZHW15-alchemy-of-souls-s01e07-netnaija-com-mp4") is by clicking the button in this page ("https://www.thenetnaija.net/videos/kdrama/16426-alchemy-of-souls/season-1/episode-7").

Also, this is my python code:

```
def gen_link(url):
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {token}', 
        'Content-Type':'application/json', 
        }
    print(dUrl)
    resp = requests.get(dUrl, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
    print(resp.url)
```

how is it that the destination url is somewhat blocked and can only be accessed if i click the button from the referrer webpage?

Answer (score 0):

The issues with your script is the lack of the http request referer header

Here is a YouTube video to further explain this [Unable to access link except by clicking button on websit](https://youtu.be/_xXiRUsXjsk)

Here is the code snippet

import requests

url='https://www.thenetnaija.net/videos/kdrama/16426-alchemy-of-souls/season-1/episode-7/download'

headers={'Referer':'https://www.thenetnaija.net/videos/kdrama/16426-alchemy-of-souls/season-1/episode-7'}

resp = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print(resp.text)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).